# ffmpeg Copy and convert specific stream and mux into file with single command

Tags: ffmpeg

If I have a video file with 1 video streams, 2 DTS audio streams, and 2 subtitle streams, can I convert a DTS stream to ac3 and mux it into a file with a single command?

Currently I used a command like this (stream 0:1 is DTS-HD) to extract the audio and convert it to AC3, then I have to manually mux it back in using `-map`.  Is there a way to cut out that 2nd command and just convert and mux in the new stream to a new file?

```
  ffmpeg -y -i "media.mkv" -map 0:1 -c:a ac3 -b:a 640k newmedia.mkv
```

ALSO: The DTS streams are 5.1 surround sound.  Do I have to do anything special to preserve those channels, or will they automatically convert over?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i "media.mkv" -map 0 -c copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k newmedia.mkv.
```

In the command above, the first output audio stream is encoded to AC3, with a bitrate set for it. All other streams are copied.

If the encoder supports the channel count and layout then they will be preserved. AC3 does, IIRC.